# In App Purchase: "native" and 3rd party allowed simultaneously?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, braintree

Currently users can pay for our service via in app purchase (iOS/Android) within the app itself. Is it allowed to use a 3rd party payment method in parallel (for the same price), e.g. Braintree/Paypal? Or to switch back and forth between both methods, i.e. to sometimes use iOS/Android in app and sometimes the 3rd party framework (again: always for the same price) with A/B testing?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can't use any 3rd party payment method to unlock digital content from within your app. You can't even link people out to your website to pay via a 3rd party method.

This blog has a good summary at the bottom -> [Don't Fear The Apple Tax](https://www.revenuecat.com/2019/02/20/what-to-get-right)

They say in most cases the distribution and low-friction checkout experience you get through in-app purchases generally outweighs the 30% transaction fee.